# bank account structure output from a data set (this is a assignment)

Tags: c++

I have been asked to build the below. At this stage I've only been able to write the tasks corresponding .h files, and unfortunately despite hours of research and due to woes of being a distance education student my teacher is not giving me assistance. I'm unsure if these .h structs are correct and I'm unsure where to start for creating a function. Can you tell me if my .h files are right and can you tell me how to create this .h file corresponding functions?

- The Customer structure (defined in a header file Customer.h) containing three members:
  Customer Name, User ID and Pin.

  ```
  #ifndef CUSTOMER_H
  #define CUSTOMER_H
  using namespace std;

  struct customer
  {
      std::string name;
      std::string pin;
      std::string user_id
  };
  ```
- A function `CreateCustomer()` that creates a Customer. It has three parameters to initialise each member of the structure (Customer Name, User ID, and PinNumber). All parameters should have default parameter blank values are to be specified. Prototype:
  Customer* CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin)

> Customer* CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin) {
>       return new Customer { name, id, pin };

- The Transaction structure (defined in a header file Transaction.h) containing three members:Transaction Date, Description and Amount. The Amount can’t be negative value.

  > // the .h file
  >
  > ```
  > struct Transaction 
  > {
  >     std::string date;
  >     std::string description;
  >     double amount;
  > };
  > ```
- A function CreateTransaction() that creates a Transaction. It has three parameters to initialise each member of the structure (Transaction Date, Description and Amount). All parameters should have default parameter values are to be specified. The Date sets to "01/01/2014", the Description is blank and amount is zero. Prototype:
  Transaction* CreateTransaction(const string& date, const string& description, const double& amount))

  > ```
  > transaction* CreateTransaction(const string& date, const string& description, const double& amount) {return new transaction { date, description, amount};
  > ```
- The Account structure (defined in a header file Account.h) containing seven members:
  Account Holder, Number, Balance, Total Deposit, Total Withdrawal, Transaction List array of
  maximum 100 records and Transaction count on the existing transaction records.

  > ```
  > // the .h file 
  > struct Account 
  >   {
  >     Customer customer;
  >     int number;
  >     double balance, total_deposit, total_withdrawal}
  > ```
- A function CreateAccount() that creates an Account. It has six parameters to initialise each appropriate member of the structure. The date parameter use to create the first transaction for the Transaction List array, the description is Opening balance from the balance parameter. Therefore, the Transaction count should be set to one after the Account is created. All parameters from the third one should have default parameter values are to be specified. The Date sets to "01/01/2014", the balance, deposit and withdraw set to zero value. Prototype:

  > Account* CreateAccount(const Customer& customer, const std::string&
  >   openingDate = "01/01/2014", const double& openingBalance = 0, const
  >   double& deposit = 0, const double& withdraw = 0);

with the above in mind I have been given a data set and the idea is that it used to have a certain output they code provided with my assignment sheet is pasted below

```
> Provided Code - main() int main() { Customer* Mary =
> CreateCustomer("Mary Jones", "235718", "5074"); Customer* John =
> CreateCustomer("John Smith", "375864", "3251"); Account* MaryAccount =
> CreateAccount(*Mary, "06-3121-10212357", "01/03/2014", 100); Account*
> JohnAccount = CreateAccount(*John, "06-3121-10213758", "10/03/2014");
> RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("01/03/2014", "ATM
> Withdrawal", 50) ); RecordDeposit(MaryAccount,
> CreateTransaction("02/03/2014", "Deposit", 90) );
> RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("04/03/2014", "ATM
> Withdrawal", 150) ); RecordDeposit(MaryAccount,
> CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Deposit", 20) );
> RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("05/03/2014",
> "Withdraw", 100) ); RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount,
> CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Withdraw", 50) );
> RecordDeposit(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("11/03/2014", "Deposit",
> 20) ); RecordDeposit(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("12/03/2014",
> "Deposit", 80) ); RecordWithdraw(JohnAccount,
> CreateTransaction("12/03/2014", "Withdraw", 50) );
> PrintReport(MaryAccount); PrintReport(JohnAccount); return 0; }
```

Comment: thanks so much wooble ive jumped back in and formatted.

Comment: Well... You hit the "" button instead of the {} button, which doesn't give nice code formatting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry sir if I've offended you with my previous comment. What I wanted to recommend is for you to learn the very basics of the language that you probably missed in class.

I'm going to sum the main points, right here, for you to refresh your memory:

#### Include guards

Their purpose is to prevent the program from including multiple definitions. Their common syntax is the following:

```
#ifndef X
#define X

    ...

#endif
```

This is done so that when the file is first included, `ifndef X` will "evaluate" to `true` in the preprocessor and the body of the `ifndef` will be entered (the body ends where `#endif` ends). The first thing the body should do is define `X` so that the next time the file is included, `ifndef` will "evaluate" to `false` in the preprocessor and will "skip" the definitions contained within the body.

The identifier `X` should of course be unique for every file.

#### `using namespace` directives

When you include `<string>` (notice that the header should not contain `.h`) you include the `string` class which is defined within the `std` namespace. Now you have two choices:

1. refer to the class with `std::string`
2. import the `std` namespace with `using namespace std;` and be able to refer to the class with `string`

This first is commonly considered better, but in academic environments the second is mostly used. Just pick one way and stick to it.

#### Other little things

```
std Transaction[]
```

doesn't mean anything. Every statement/declaration should end with a semicolon (`;`) and you already do in other parts of the program.

#### The customer structure

Your customer structure should contain:

- name
- user id
- pin

The name can be expressed with a string, therefore I'd use `std::string` for that. The used ID and the pin look like numeric values to me, therefore I'd probably use `int` for both, leading the structure to be:

```
struct Customer
{
    std::string name;
    int pin;
    int user_id;
};
```

#### The function `CreateCustomer`

This is the assigment:

> A function CreateCustomer() that creates a Customer. It has three parameters to initialize each member of the structure (Customer Name, User ID, and PinNumber). All parameters should have default parameter blank values are to be specified.
>
> Prototype: `Customer* CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin)`

From the return type I'm actually scared about what the assignment is asking you to do. He is probably asking you to return a dynamically allocated object, which is **very** poor practice. But just for the sake of the assignment this is simple and you can do this with:

```
Customer* CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin) {
    return new Customer { name, id, pin };
}
```

There's not much to explain about this. This is dynamically allocated memory, you should remember to `delete` it later as well. The topic of "dynamic memory" is definitely too long to be explained well here, just read the chapter of your book that explains it.

#### The `Transaction` structure

The sketch you have drawn for this one is quite accurate actually. `std::string` for both description and date and `double` for the amount. The only thing is that you shouldn't worry about prepending `Transaction` prefixes to the names as they are local to the `Transaction` struct anyway:

```
struct Transaction {
    std::string date;
    std::string description;
    double amount;
};
```

#### The `CreateTransaction` function

This is pretty much identical to the previous `CreateCustomer` function. Now that we have the `Transaction` this should be trivial. I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader.

#### The `Account`

The assignment is asking for:

- account holder
- number
- balance
- total deposit
- total withdrawal
- transaction array of maximum 100 records
- transaction count on the existing transaction records

For the account holder we have our nice brand new `Customer` class. For the number we can use an `int` again. For `balance`, `total_deposit` and `total_withdrawal` we can use a `double` (when handling money, floating point numbers are needed to express cents).

So the `struct` should look like this:

```
struct Account {
    Customer customer;
    int number;
    double balance, total_deposit, total_withdrawal;
```

Now for the array this gets confusing. On one hand it looks like your professor wants you to use a C-array, on the other (transaction count) it seems like you should something more dynamic. In my opinion you should include `<vector>` and use an `std::vector`. If you haven't talked about vectors you can use an array:

```
    Transaction transactions[100];
};
```

#### The confusing `CreateAccount`

Here the assignment is pretty confusing, at least for me and apparently there's no prototype, but I'm sure you can work your solution out by revising:

- `for` loops
- arrays
- `new`

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @Jefffrey, here are a few more things I noted in your program.

```
struct CUSTOMER_H
{
    std::string name[8];
    std::string pin;
    std::string Userid;
};
```

It looks like you got confused about the difference between char-based strings and `std::string`. With a C-style char-based string, you create an array of `char`. The array has to be fixed-size and you have to leave the last element for a trailing null, `\0`, which marks the end of the string. So in this case, you'd do something like this:

```
char name[8]; //this creates a character array with 8 elements numbered 0-7. You need to leave name[7] alone so it can hold the trailing \0, though, or you'll crash your program. So this can effectively hold a 7-character name.
```

But since you're using `std::string` everywhere else, you probably meant to do that here too. Unlike a char-based string, `std::string` is a variable-length string and it takes care of marking its own ending. You don't need to create an array here; just

```
std::string name;
```

will do.

> The Transaction structure (defined in a header file Transaction.h) containing three members:Transaction Date, Description and Amount. The Amount can’t be negative value.

It sounds like the Transaction structure is meant to be a bit more complex than just a data container: if you're making sure the amount never goes negative, you'll need to use *getters* and *setters*. These are simple functions designed to provide some control over what's assigned to a variable. They work like this:

```
//Transaction.h: we're just declaring things here
struct Transaction
{
  //<snip>
  double getAmount();
  void setAmount(double newAmount);

private:
  double amount;
}
```

The `getAmount` function will, as the name implies, return the value stored in `amount`. The `setAmount` function should check to make sure `newAmount` is positive, and only store it in `amount` if it is positive. Also worth noting is the `private` keyword: our special getters and setters don't do much for us if anyone using a Transaction can see and change the `amount` variable directly, so `private` lets us hide it from anything outside the Transaction class. This way, only code within the Transaction class gets to change `amount`.

I doubt you've seen these in action before, so I'll write them for you:

```
//Transaction.cpp: we're actually implementing things here. Yey code!

double Transaction::getAmount() //note that we prefix the method name with the class name and a double colon. This is required when you're creating a class method.
{
  return amount; //short and sweet. We don't need to do anything special here, we're just letting outside code see the value of amount since they can't access it directly.
}

void Transaction::setAmount(double newAmount)
{
  if (newAmount > 0) //this is why we're doing the whole getter-setter thing. Now we get to control what goes into amount: amount will only be updated if newAmount > 0.
  {
    amount = newAmount;
  }
}
```

> The Account structure (defined in a header file Account.h) containing seven members: Account Holder, Number, Balance, Total Deposit, Total Withdrawal, Transaction List array of maximum 100 records and Transaction count on the existing transaction records.

@Jefffrey's answer here was quite good, so you should mostly follow it. I just wanted to note one small thing: the transaction list/transaction count. (Okay, two small things.)

Based on what I've seen of intro-level classes, I'd be willing to bet you haven't covered `std::vector` yet, and the fixed-size array requirement supports this idea. What your professor is probably looking for is a C-style array of Transactions with a separate transaction counter variable:

```
struct Account
{
  //<snip>
  Transaction transactions[100];
  int transactionCount;
}
```

Again, make sure you keep in mind that the `transactions` array is accessed via indexes 0-99, **not** 1-100. So if `transactionCount` is 2, that **does not mean** you can access `transactions[1]` and `transactions[2]`. Your code will do things you won't appreciate, ranging from returning garbage values to possibly crashing. You want `transactions[0]` and `transactions[1]` instead. Also, don't use `std::int`; just declare an integer variable as `int`.

> A function CreateAccount() that creates an Account. It has six parameters to initialise each appropriate member of the structure. The date parameter use to create the first transaction for the Transaction List array, the description is Opening balance from the balance parameter. Therefore, the Transaction count should be set to one after the Account is created. All parameters from the third one should have default parameter values are to be specified. The Date sets to "01/01/2014", the balance, deposit and withdraw set to zero value.

This is quite confusing, but let's try to break it down.

CreateAccount:

- creates an Account
- has six parameters, but only date, balance, deposit, and withdrawal are accounted for. Based on a bit of intuition and the declaration of your Account struct, one of the missing parameters is likely a Customer object.

  - has default values for most of the parameters
  - does a bit of setup work

The code for this is likely to be incomplete or somewhat wrong because of the lack of information, but I'll do the best I can to work with what you've provided.

```
//CreateAccount prototype:
Account* CreateAccount(const Customer& customer, const std::string& openingDate = "01/01/2014", const double& openingBalance = 0, const double& deposit = 0, const double& withdraw = 0);
```

First, there's one missing parameter. I don't know what it is so I can't add it; you'll need to do that.

Also, note that we're returning `Account*` - a pointer to an account. This is a **very bad idea** and generally you just want to return an `Account` - that's a normal Account object that won't cause you headaches with manual memory allocation/deallocation. Unfortunately, this professor seems to be fond of returning dynamically-created objects, so we'll need to do it his way. *Please* don't do this in real code without a very good reason.

Finally, note the `= <value>` (`= 0`, `= "01/01/2014"`) - that's how you specify default parameter values. Whoever calls `CreateAccount` will be able to skip those parameters, and the ones we specified in the prototype will be used instead. Or they can call `CreateAccount` and specify all the parameters, and our default values will be overridden. So all three of these calls are valid:

```
//for the purposes of the next few lines of code, JoeCool is a valid Customer object that we've already set up using CreateCustomer.
CreateAccount(JoeCool); //creates an account belonging to JoeCool. The opening date will be automatically set to 01/01/2014 and the balance, deposit and withdrawal will all be set to 0.
CreateAccount(JoeCool, "09/10/14"); //creates an account belonging to JoeCool. The opening date will be set to 09/10/14, overriding our default date; however, since we didn't specify a balance, deposit, or withdrawal, they'll all be set to 0.
CreateAccount(JoeCool, "12/11/15", 50, 100, 25); //creates an account belonging to JoeCool. We've overridden all our default parameters, so the opening date will be set to 12/11/15, the opening balance will be set to 50, the deposit will be set to 100, and the withdrawal will be set to 25.
```

I'll leave actually implementing this as an exercise for you. However, there are a few general concepts I think you'll want to keep in mind as you do this.

- Code is broken into functions for a reason. Don't try to do everything in `CreateAccount`; pass some of that work off to `CreateTransaction`.
- Don't forget to keep your transaction array in sync with your transaction counter. This might get very messy; I'd suggest experimenting with some getter and setter type methods, such as `getTransactionCount` (no setter for this! The transaction count will be incremented internally, there's no need for any outside code to set it), `getTransaction(int index)`, and of course `CreateTransaction`. This way, `CreateTransaction` can create a new Transaction and increment the transaction counter, `getTransaction` can return one individual Transaction item instead of giving outside code access to your full Transaction array, and `getTransactionCount` can make sure outside code isn't messing with your transaction counter.
- Don't forget your sanity checks. Is someone trying to withdraw more money than is present in the account? This, by the way, is why you want to pass most of the work off to `CreateTransaction`: you can write sanity checks in one place and let the rest of the code make use of them, instead of having to check everything everywhere. Just make multiple transactions to set the balance, then deposit anything, then withdraw anything, and let `CreateTransaction` decide if the calling code is doing something illegal (negative deposits, negative balances, withdrawals bigger than the balance).

Comment: computerfreaker and Jefffrey thank you so much for your time and effort in replying your help is worth gold. Id like to apologise for formatting related issues in my question, first post to stack but i shall know for the future. I forgot to add the teachers data set where by this will create a output i shall go ahead and add this to my question. i have applied the advice to the structs, but i may have seek further assistance with the functions ill give it a go writing them tonight, thank you once again

Comment: @user3478192 No problem! If you have any further issues with your code, feel free to ask a new question. I'd suggest you leave this one closed, since general StackOverflow policy is to ask one question per thread. Don't forget to accept Jefffrey's answer, by the way; you can do this by clicking the checkmark next to it. This will give both of you some reputation points, and is generally considered a good thing to do when someone's provided the answer to your question.